While going through a paper I am confused in this part of the problem.
The left inverse of an operator $T\in L(\mathcal{H})$ is $L:=(T^{*}T)^{-1}T^{*}$ whose null space is $E=ker~T^{*}$. How can we show that $P_{E}=I-TL$. Here, $P_E$ is the orthogonal projector to $E$.

Guessing we should have that $T^\ast T$ is invertible.
You can show that $T L$ is the orthogonal projector to $E^\bot$, from which it follows that $I - TL$ is the orthogonal projector to $E$. So you need to verify that:

$T L$ is Hermitian ($(T L)^\ast = T L$);
$(T L)^2 = T L$;
The kernel of $T L$ is $E$.

By general theory (e.g. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Characterization_of_Projections), the first two conditions show that $T L$ is a projection $P_F$ for the closed subspace $F = \mathrm{Img}(T L)$. We then have that $\ker(T L) = F^\bot$. Then, if we can show that $F^\bot = E$, we will have $F^{\bot \bot} = E^\bot$. Since $F$ is a closed subspace, we will have $F = E^\bot$.
It is really then just a matter of writing everything out. For example for the third point, note that if $T (T^\ast T)^{-1} T^\ast x = 0$ then by applying $T^\ast$ to both sides we obtain that $T^\ast x = 0$. The converse is clear. You may also want to recall that $(T^\ast)^{-1} = (T^{-1})^\ast$.
